# How to group rows into one but keeping all the values from other columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

please help!:)
I have a problem like this in SQL:

```
ID column1 column2 column3 column4 
1240742             0   0   1   0
1240742             1   0   0   0
1240753             0   0   0   1
1240753             0   0   1   0
1240753             1   0   0   0
```

The IDs are duplicated, so what I want is to achieve that the ID is unique, but the values in the columns are all saved in one row for that ID. In other words, I need the result to become this:

```
ID column1 column2 column3 column4 
1240742             1   0   1   0
1240753             1   0   1   1
```

Any suggestions are welcome, I have tried for two days and cannot find the solution.

Comment: You'll have more chance of help if you [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: Do you want to create a select only that shows the data or do you want to change the data in your table to the result of this select?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate by the `ID` and then select the sum of all other columns:

```sql
SELECT ID, SUM(column1) column1, SUM(column2) column2, SUM(column3) column3,
           SUM(column4) column4
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```